# mozjs_global_environment.cc(465)] JS Error

Tags: javascript, mips, cobalt

log is as below:

JS:11125:app-prod.js(582,1): Error: Error, injector cannot find declaration for "window" while attempting to create "temp".
ERROR:mozjs_global_environment.cc(465)] JS Error: https://www.youtube.com/s/tv/html5/181ca9fe/app-prod.js:582:0: Error: Error, injector cannot find declaration for "window" while attempting to create "temp"

thanks very much

Comment: This sounds like a bug more than a technical question? You can file bugs on COBALT at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:181120

Comment: Please provide steps to reproduce and expected result.

Comment: this issue we met is produced on MIPS , toolchain is 4.8.3.  By the way ,it works well on ARM.