# Cobalt crash on MIPS platform when javascript JIT is enabled

Tags: javascript, mips, cobalt

When javascript JIT is enabled on MIPS platform with `'cobalt_enable_jit': 1,`,
I get the following error:

`[ERROR:mozjs_global_environment.cc(471)] JS Error: https://www.youtube.com/s/tv/html5/55391e4a/app-prod.js:919:0: Error: Error, injector cannot find declaration for "window" while attempting to create "temp".`

Is it supposed to work? or do I have an issue in my build?

Comment: Same kind of issue was already reported in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348161/mozjs-global-environment-cc465-js-error

Comment: Yes, MIPS JIT is not supported in Cobalt until it is on mozjs-45.